# How to make a reminder in C# using System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple appointment remainder app where I would get remainder of an appointment 15 minutes earlier to the appointment time. I am calling the timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) function on form load.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        //now = now.AddMinutes(10);
        now = now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        string longtime = now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");//    "03:46:00 PM";
        string shortdate = now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //"21/02/2015";
        MySqlCommand cmdchk = new MySqlCommand("select * from tbl_appointment where adate=@adte and atime=@time", con);
        cmdchk.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adte", shortdate);
        cmdchk.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", longtime);
        dr = cmdchk.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                appointmentid = dr.GetInt32(0);
                smsmobile = dr.GetString(2);
            }
            dr.Close();
            Frm_app_pop pop = new Frm_app_pop();
            pop.appointmentid = appointmentid.ToString();
            pop.Show();
            words[0] = appointmentid;
        }
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();
        if (flags.remiderflag == true)
        {
            remindtimer.Start();
        }
        dr.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exce = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I have set the time interval to 1 second. For every second, the timer1_Tick function is run which connects to database and gets the time in `longtime` which is the the time on which I want to set the reminder.

When I run this code, it runs fine but I am not getting any reminder (which should be displayed using `pop.show()`), neither there is any error in this code.

Please share a solution to this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MessagingException while trying to read emails from Gmail using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667657/messagingexception-while-trying-to-read-emails-from-gmail-using-java)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your question from a few days ago, and you don't seem to have followed any of my advice there.  In fact, your code is getting worse.  Start [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: @Bill Shannon:I tested the code with the changes suggested by you but the code was still not working..thats why I started with a new question.If you could please point me what changes should I make in my code, it would be very helpfull.Thank you

Comment: I did tell you what changes to make.  Did you read the FAQ?  Did you use the code there?

Comment: Yeah I made the changes exactly as it is given there with my username and password but when I use "imaps"(as given in the FAQ) instead of "imap" I get an exception of

javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for imaps

Comment: The exception is thrown on this line

Store store=session.getStore("imaps");

Comment: Are you sure you're not still using JavaMail 1.2?  What's in your CLASSPATH?  What does the Session debugging output show when it fails?

Comment: I have posted all the details and recent changes made to my code in this question 
[Error while receiving inbox mails from gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726606/error-while-receiving-inbox-mails-from-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

Check your network connectivity and firewall checking. From command line, you have to run the following commands and if it is succeeded, you can send mail.

1. ping google.com
2. tracert  google.com

After that put ssl.enable property to false.

Comment: the second command is not working it says "No command 'tracert' found".I am using ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the value of the `mail.imap.connectiontimeout` javamail property, for example to `10000`.